# Powershell Script to find and delete a subkey in the Registry for all users

Tags: powershell, registry

I am attempting to find and delete a specific Subkey and it's contents for each user of the computer.

I found this post: https://www.pdq.com/blog/modifying-the-registry-users-powershell/ which does most of what I need it to do. However, I need to not only search the registry, but to also delete a subkey and it's contents.

Here is the script that I've copied from the above mentioned site:

```
$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'
$ProfileList = gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' | Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -match $PatternSID} | 
    Select  @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}}, 
            @{name="UserHive";expression={"$($_.ProfileImagePath)\ntuser.dat"}}, 
            @{name="Username";expression={$_.ProfileImagePath -replace '^(.*[\\\/])', ''}}

$LoadedHives = gci Registry::HKEY_USERS | ? {$_.PSChildname -match $PatternSID} | Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.PSChildName}}

$UnloadedHives = Compare-Object $ProfileList.SID $LoadedHives.SID | Select @{name="SID";expression={$_.InputObject}}, UserHive, Username

Foreach ($item in $ProfileList) {
    IF ($item.SID -in $UnloadedHives.SID) {
        reg load HKU\$($Item.SID) $($Item.UserHive) | Out-Null
    }

    "{0}" -f $($item.Username) | Write-Output
    Get-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_USERS\$($Item.SID)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
        Foreach {"{0} {1}" -f "   Program:", $($_.DisplayName) | Write-Output}
    Get-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_USERS\$($Item.SID)\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
        Foreach {"{0} {1}" -f "   Program:", $($_.DisplayName) | Write-Output}
}
```

This returns a list of all programs installed per user. However, when I try to delete the subkey using this command, I get an error that the path could not be found. What am I doing wrong?

```
Remove-Item -Path HKEY_USERS\$($Item.SID)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Test
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to prepend the registry path with `registry::`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I amended it to:
```Remove-Item Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($Item.SID)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Test```
But that still gave me the same error. I also tried:
```Remove-Item -Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($Item.SID)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Test```